# Internet Explorer not handling any event thrown by window opened with window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When I open a simple HTML page from the same domain (so no cross domain concerns here) in a new window/tab with [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

```
var mywindow = window.open('<html page on same domain>');
```

Then the following code, which according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) is even <IE9 compatible

```
if (mywindow.addEventListener) {
    mywindow.addEventListener('load', function () {
        console.log('load event fired');
    }, false);
} else if (mywindow.attachEvent) {
    mywindow.attachEvent('onload', function () {
        console.log('load event fired');
    });
}
```

Doesn't catch the event thrown (tested in IE11 and IE Edge). Even if I throw a custom event on the HTML page [the old fashioned way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#The_old-fashioned_way):

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('customEvent', true, true);
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

It it not caught... Also with jQuery, no success:

```
$(mywindow).on("customEvent", function () {
    console.log('custom event fired');
});
```

Chrome and Firefox however **do** catch both of the events...

Is this by design? Am I missing something? Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: What are you trying to _achieve_? As for possible “solutions”/workarounds - if you are writing HTML into the popup manually, then you might as well include the event handler code in there, for example …

Comment: @CBroe I'm trying to open a HTML page as a template for printing. It's a clean page with a bootstrap reference and some print styling in there. I try to set some generated HTML in there for printing. Works great in Chrome and FF, but not in IE. Then I found out that no event was fired at all.

Comment: And what do you need the load event for in that scenario? (If it is to call the `print` method automatically once all content has loaded, as I said I’d simply do that from within the popup.)

Comment: I need the load event for setting the content in the html page. I use this page as a template. When I remove the load event and immediately set the content, then it oddly enough works for IE, but not (as expected) for Chrome and FF. It won't find the div for filling the content. The html is loaded asynchronously, so I assume you'll have to wait for the HTML to be loaded before you can set some content, right?

Comment: Can’t you load your template upfront and populate it with the data in your main page - and then just write the complete HTML, including the already inserted data, into the popup?

Comment: I might certainly give that a try. Thanks for the tip. I was still wondering however why catching these events from a popup is not working for IE only.

Comment: Perhaps the load event occurs so quickly, that your attempt to bind a handler to it, which only happens after the window.open call, comes too late already …?

Comment: You're so right! When I wrap throwing the custom event in a setTimeout, delaying by 1 sec, the event is captured. I guess I need to wrap this delayed throwing of the custom event in the window.onload function of the popup html: `window.onload = function() { setTimeout(function() { ... <throw custom event> ... }, 1000 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the page was already loaded, before I was able to attach a handler to the load event.

I managed to solve this (thanks @CBroe) by triggering a delayed custom event in a window onload handler on the page, opened with window.open.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('customEvent', true, true);
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, 1000);
};
</script>
```

This way I'm sure the window has fully been loaded (it's triggered in window.onload), but is not triggered too fast for attaching a handler to this custom event.

The delay of 1 sec has been chosen arbitrarily. You might want to adjust this to your needs.